# Write a List of Strings into CSV file

Tags: jenkins, groovy

```
list[0] = "ilocpde406,Pass,Pass,w38,Used,oc-cd-22-02"
list[1] = "ilocpde406,Pass,Pass,w39,Available,NA"
list[2] = "ilocpde406,Pass,Pass,w40,Available,NA"
```

Output:

```
Cluster      NTNET INTEG  NodeName  Status     Namespace
ilocpde406   Pass  Pass   w38       Used       oc-cd-22-02
ilocpde406   Pass  Pass   w39       Available  NA
etc..
```

I thought about splitting using the comma, and appending each line with all the elements, but I was wondering if there is a better approach for this in Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

Using split / replace is not a bad idea.

Down below is one of thousand ways to do it:

```
def list = []
list << 'Cluster,NTNET,INTEG,NodeName,Status,Namespace'
list << "ilocpde406,Pass,Pass,w38,Used,oc-cd-22-02" 
list << "ilocpde406,Pass,Pass,w39,Available,NA" 
list << "ilocpde406,Pass,Pass,w40,Available,NA"

StringWriter out = new StringWriter() // or File
list.eachWithIndex{ item, ix ->
  if( ix ) out << '\n'
  item.split( ',' ).each{ out << it.padRight( 12, ' ' ) }
}
out
```

prints

```
Cluster     NTNET       INTEG       NodeName    Status      Namespace   
ilocpde406  Pass        Pass        w38         Used        oc-cd-22-02 
ilocpde406  Pass        Pass        w39         Available   NA          
ilocpde406  Pass        Pass        w40         Available   NA
```

If you want do add fancyness, you can scan the list for max column sizes and `padRight` each item with respective size.

Comment: it doesn't work in Jenkins

Comment: how exactly?...